# How are roles, authorities identified at JSP side in Spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I encountered the following code in a jsp. How are these Authorities being passed on to the JSP? In the DB, I have individual tables for roles, authorities, users. There is a one to many relation between Role and Authority. Similarly one to many relation also exists between users and roles. At UI side, if the logged in user does not have any one out of AUTHORITY1 OR AUTHORITY2 in the DB, the following div won't be visible to him.

```
<security:authorize ifAnyGranted="AUTHORITY1, AUTHORITY2">
<div>
    <b> 123123123</b>
</div>
</security:authorize>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are held in Spring Security Context. During Spring Security authorization your UserDetailsService is extracting these authorities from database, later they are assigned to Authentication object in Spring Security Context ([SecurityContext documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html)).

[UserDetailsService documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html)